# Caesar Cipher In C

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, caesar-cipher

I've been staring at this problem for weeks and i have nothing! It doesn't work, I know that much, but I don't know why or what's wrong. I do know that the developer spits out "error: expected expression" regarding the line i highlighted, but really that's just the tip of the ice berg. If anyone at all knows how to fix any small piece of this I would greatly appreciate it!!!!!

Okay so I changes the i < n and >= like you amazing helpers suggested and it will run through and create but there's still a glitch that causes these unsightly errors:

```
:( encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
   \ expected output, not an exit code of 0
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
   \ expected output, not an exit code of 0
:( encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
   \ expected output, but not "E\nA\nU\nI\nR\nR\n"
:( encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
```

Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    //Get the key
    if (argc != 2 || atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
       {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar k");
       return 1;
       }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    string plaintext = GetString();

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (plaintext[i] > 'A' && plaintext[i] <= 'Z')
            {
            plaintext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
            }
    }


    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
    {           
       if (plaintext[i]  >= 'A' && plaintext[i] >= 'Z')
       {
       plaintext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';
       }
       else if (plaintext[i] >= 'a' && plaintext[i] < 'z')
       {
       plaintext[i] = (plaintext[i] - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a';
       }
       else
       {
            printf("%c\n", plaintext[i]);
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

=> is not a valid operator. Use >=

also, i < n in your for loops, not n < i.

and your second for loop is not really necessary. just puts(plaintext);

Answer (score 0):

Change your following line

```
if (plaintext[i] => 'A' && plaintext[i] >= 'Z')
```

to

> if (plaintext[i] >= 'A' && plaintext[i] >= 'Z')

you should be using **>=** instead of **=>**.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I just don't understand this problem at all!